# How to use cls-hooked unmanaged transactions?

Tags: jestjs, transactions, sequelize.js, unmanaged, cls-hooked

I'm writing tests with jest and sequelize and I need to keep my database clean for every test, so I want to set a transaction for every test and then rollback at the end.

This is what I've got, but it wont pass the transaction to my tests:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  this.transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
});

test('Database should be clean', async () => {
  const role = await db.role.create({
    name: 'someName',
  });
  expect(role.id).toBe(1);
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await this.transaction.rollback();
});
```

Sequelize is already setted to use cls

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../../config/config.js');
const cls = require('cls-hooked');

const namespace = cls.createNamespace('testing-namespace');
Sequelize.useCLS(namespace);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);
...
```

It would be really helpful if somenone could explain me how to use unmanaged transactions with cls-hooked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to keep my database clean by using [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) to run seeds programatically, this is my code:

```
const { db } = require('../models');
const Umzug = require('umzug');
const path = require('path');

const umzug = new Umzug({
  migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './../../seeders'),
    params: [db.sequelize.getQueryInterface()],
  },
  logging: false,
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const reverted = await umzug.down({ to: 0 });
  const executed = await umzug.up();
});
```

I tried to use umzug v3 (beta), but it didn't work, so I used the [stable version 2](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/tree/v2.x). This approach isn't as performant as I'd like, but gets the job done.